# Vector adding a element

Tags: java, vector

Can we perform this operation on vector ?

```
    Vector object = (Vector) listUserEvents.get(key);
    object.addElement(eCompare);
```

I have no instance here

Comment: ya sometimes it works and sometimes not

Comment: @harqs - we'll need more information than that.  Or else, the best answer is "yes"

Comment: What does "I have no instance here" mean?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to, `Vector` does still have the [`addElement` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#addElement%28E%29); it's just a duplicate of the newer [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add%28E%29) method.

---

**Update**

Below you've said:

> my question is not related to add/addElement ,here i am asking without the instance of vector can i add data as per above snippet?

It certainly *seems* to be about `add`/`addElement`.

You're casting the result of the `get` to a `Vector`. If it's not a `Vector`, that'll be a runtime `ClassCastException`. Fundamentally you need to ensure you're dealing with the correct interface to whatever the object is you're getting back. If it's really a `Vector`, then you can use `addElement` on it. If it's one of the `List` implementations, then cast it to `List` and use `add`.

---

Separately, unless you really need the synchronization, use `ArrayList` or one of the other, newer `List` implementations. `Vector` is a bit of a remnant of history, from the earliest (and quite poor) initial collections stuff in Java, superceded over a decade ago by the [newer collections framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) (which while still not brilliant, was a step forward).

Comment: Actually TJ, `Vector` DOES have an `addElement` operation.  It is one of the "legacy" methods from before the Collections framework.

Comment: @StephenC: Thanks, yes, you were typing as I was editing. Got my head backward there for a mo. :-)

Comment: my question is not related to add/addElement ,here i am asking without the instance of vector can i add data as per above snippet? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @harqs: The question certainly *seems* to be about `addElement`, as that's darned near the only code you've shown. How 'bout taking the time to explain what you're really trying to do?

Comment: Vector object = null;
object = (Vector) listUserEvents.get(key); after this i can use this object to add a new element to it,i dont have Vector object=new Vector(); @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @harqs: Whether that will work depends entirely on what `listUserEvents.get(key)` returns. If it returns a `Vector`, then it will work. If it doesn't, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we perform this operation on vector ?

Yes you can.

The operation exists, and it works.

If you have a problem with the above code, it is something to do with the larger context and / or your expectations of what the code does.  But without more information we can only guess what your problem is, and what might be causing it.

---

> I have no instance here

I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Vector object = null;
object = (Vector) listUserEvents.get(key); after this i can use this object to add a new element to it,i dont have Vector object=new Vector();